# Is multiplication Comutitive in numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is multiplication comutitive  in numbers
I.e

Is 
N×M equal    M×N??
Where N and M any numbers

And why??

Comment: Of course not. $N\times M=M\times N^2$.

Comment: For quaternions no, since for example $ij=-ji$, but for fields $K$ yes, because the group $(K^{\times},\cdot)$ is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "numbers". Complex numbers commute, as do special cases thereof, such as integers. However, quaternions don't in general commute, so nor do more inclusive systems such as the octonions.

Comment: But  Z ,R,Q,and C are comutitive  rings with identity

Comment: @user479750 As I said, $\Bbb Z\subseteq\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb R\subseteq\Bbb C$ ensures these sets all commute, but $\Bbb H$ doesn't.